# Change position of figure in fancytikzposter

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, tikzposter

I downloaded the source from fancytikzposter and I am trying to insert the figure inside. I met the problem with the figure, I don't know why all of my figures just move to right. I tried to add `\centering` or `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and apply `\includegraphics[scale=0.4,inner,left]{programming}` but it didn't work either.

A sample of my code:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Programming language definition]
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4,inner,left]{programming}
        \label{fig:1}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzfigure}
```

I also met problem when I try to insert table inside the poster, my sample table:

```
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
 Rank & TIOBE index & RedMonk & GitHub & Combination & Salary (USD) \\ 
 \hline
 1 & C & JavaScript  & JavaScript & Java &  93,991 \\  
 2 & Java & Java & Java & JavaScript & 93,142\\ 
 3 & Objective-C & PHP & Python & PHP & 92,387\\
 4 & C++ & Python & CSS & Python & 96,802\\
 5 & C\# & C\# & PHP & C++ & 94,359\\
 6 & PHP & C++ & Ruby & C  & 91,258\\
 7 & JavaScript & Ruby & C++ & C\# & 92,629\\
 8 & Python & CSS & C & Objective-C & 108,225 *\\
 9 & VisualBasic .NET & C & Shell & Ruby & 109,460 *\\
 10 & VisualBasic & Objective-C & C\# & N/A & N/A \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Programming languages ranking in 2015. (*) The different source }
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

It showed me some compile errors and it was too complicated for a newbie like me to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried using `\noindent` before your `\begin{tikzfigure}`?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: And please quote that "some compile errors" or give us the minimal example, which produces them.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`. Helps here. I can see no issue with that table, though.

Comment: Agreed, look like `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` made everything problem, I removed it and everything worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fancytikzposter` is obsolete and `tikzposter` is recommended instead.

Figures and tables in `tikzposter` *must* be inserted through the `tikzfigure` environment.

Here is an example of how to insert your stuff in `\block`s:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\begin{document}

\block{Some title}{%
\begin{tikzfigure}[Programming language definition]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
        \label{fig:1}
\end{tikzfigure}
}

\block{Some title}{%
\begin{tikzfigure}[Programming languages ranking in 2015. (*) The different source ]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c }
 Rank & TIOBE index & RedMonk & GitHub & Combination & Salary (USD) \\
 \hline
 1 & C & JavaScript  & JavaScript & Java &  93,991 \\
 2 & Java & Java & Java & JavaScript & 93,142\\
 3 & Objective-C & PHP & Python & PHP & 92,387\\
 4 & C++ & Python & CSS & Python & 96,802\\
 5 & C\# & C\# & PHP & C++ & 94,359\\
 6 & PHP & C++ & Ruby & C  & 91,258\\
 7 & JavaScript & Ruby & C++ & C\# & 92,629\\
 8 & Python & CSS & C & Objective-C & 108,225 *\\
 9 & VisualBasic .NET & C & Shell & Ruby & 109,460 *\\
 10 & VisualBasic & Objective-C & C\# & N/A & N/A \\
\end{tabular}}
\label{table:1}
\end{tikzfigure}
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: look like `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` made everything problem, I removed it and everything worked as expected. Thank you a lot!